# Connect to openERP from others computers

Tags: android, openerp-7

I have a simple question:
I'm installing openERP server in my computer.
and i can conncte to it by typing `"http://localhost:8069"` in google chrome.

Now I ask if i can connect to my openERP server from others computers and from my mobile android in my locale network.

**EDIT:**

**so this is my situation:**

I have developped an application android to connect to an openERP.then i am installed openERP (all-in-one) on my computer.the application turn good on the emulator, now i want to connect from my phone android.
but when i typing (my_ip:8069) from my application in my phone,i can't acces to my computer.
so tell me if it is possible or no,if yes how can i do it.

thanks for suggestions.

Comment: how you connected that application to openerp?

Comment: from emulator i entre my_ip and port numbre.(i have programming this with java and XMLRPC).

Comment: this is a part of code `client_db=new XMLRPCClient(url);
Vector<Object> params=new Vector<Object>();
call_params=new Object[]{params};
call_result=(Object[]) client_db.call("list", call_params);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect by using IP of that computer.

**IP:8069** from any computer in that network.

Comment: typing     myIP:8069 dosn't work !!    any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling your firewall, it worked for me.